# In MASM what is array[4]

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32, addressing-mode

I have a code in MASM, which contains

```
mov bx, 4
mov ax, array[bx] + 4
```

So array[4] here is the fifth element of the array or 4 bytes and then we add 4 bytes ?
What will be the value of AX then?

Comment: It is important to remember that MASM doesn't do address computations the way C does.  You can't think of it as "the fourth element of the array".  These are just addresses, addressed as bytes.  Regardless of the "type" of array, this is gets you "array + 8".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number between square brackets is an offset in the array. It is a distance measured in bytes.
The number that comes after these square brackets is just another offset. It could have been inserted between the brackets too: `mov ax, array[bx+4]`. Even the address of the array itself can go between the brackets: `mov ax, [array + bx + 4]`.

AX will get the word value from the 9th (offset 8) and 10th (offset 9) bytes of the array.